# Create dynamic library using MSVC command line

Tags: c, dll, linker-errors

I've read a lot of posts and yet I don't understand how to create a simple dynamic library on windows using MSVC in command line. What I'm doing is:

1º) Code the DLL

**dynamic.h**

```c
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
```

**dynamic.c**

```c
#include "dynamic.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void HelloWorld(){
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

2º) Compile it

```
cl /LD dynamic.c
```

(it compiles correctly and without errors generating dynamic.dll and dynamic.lib)

3º) Try to test it

**main.c**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"dynamic.h"
int main(){

    HelloWorld();

    return 0;
}
```

```
cl main.c dynamic.lib
```

**ERROR** (by cl.exe x64)

```
main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27034.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
.\dynamic.lib
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl HelloWorld(void)" (?HelloWorld@@YAXXZ) referred in main
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: unresolved externals
```

Please teach me how dynamic libraries compilation really work because I can't understand

Comment: the reason is that cl will give you a c++ decorated name of your function (it includes things like parameters), you need to use extern "C" in order to ensure that the decoration is removed. it is hinted in the error message "void __cdecl.."

Comment: @AndersK but when I use extern "C" I get an error ```error C2059: Syntax error: 'string'```

Comment: in `main.c` the function needs to be declared as `__declspec(dllimport)` (not export) . You could test this out by manually declaring the function instead of including dynamic.h   , the usual way people deal with this problem is to use a preprocessor macro that gets set to export when building the DLL and import when included by clients

Comment: @M.M Thanks now it works and also I understand how it works <3

Comment: I've rolled back the last edit -- this site uses a Question and Answer format, you should not edit the question to include answers. Instead you can accept a posted answer, or write your own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main.c` it needs to see the function declaration like this:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld();
```

So you cannot use the same `dynamic.h` as you currently have, for both building the DLL and building `main.c`  .

Normally people will use a preprocessor setup so the same header file has a different declspec depending who is including it, for example:

```
// dynamic.h
#ifndef DLL_FUNCTION 
#define DLL_FUNCTION __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_FUNCTION void HelloWorld();
```

dynamic.c (in the DLL):

```
#define DLL_FUNCTION __declspec(dllexport)
#include "dynamic.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way in dynamic.h :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
extern "C" {
#endif 
    __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

Use 'dumpbin.exe /exports dynamic.dll' to show exported symbols

Comment: don't works, while compiling dynamic.dll throws and error ```error C2059:  Syntax error: 'string'```

Comment: Use 'dumpbin.exe /exports dynamic.dll' to show exported symbols.

Comment: It's the first time that I use that program but the function seems to be exported

Comment: Your libray have function name DllMain? If not include this: BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved ) {};

Comment: I've read that using DllMain it's optional, and also I've tried it before

Comment: it works... but I feel like I'm doing something illegal using __cplusplus but thanks now there are two solutions for the problem

Comment: The `extern "C"` would not be relevant to the code in the question since both are C files anyway, but probably a good idea if you intend to use the DLL from a C++ program